# Write Google sheet arrayformula in GAS code - enhance performance

Tags: performance, google-sheets-formula, unique, array-formulas

I'm sure that my code shows that I'm not very experienced with this.
When I run the script on test data (just 30 lines) it does what it is supposed to, so I'm happy with that.
But with I run the script on the actual data (approx 9000 lines) it is really slow.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Create a list (on sheet2) containing only the unique values from sheet1 column A
2. if the value in sheet1 column A has multiple identical values
3. then place the most recent date (from sheet1 column E) in sheet2 column E
4. also get the values from the other columns (B, C, D, F, G and H)

I've managed to do this by using the hardcoded (array)formulas in Sheet2, but I know this is not the best approach.
Here is the link to the file : [Form UniqData](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10VN6qhMjRdQUx7wvlAI1yo4BoMYPwbjFzRh7l6JSaro/edit?usp=sharing)
Can anyone help me improve this script?

```
function UniqueData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var md = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

    ws.getRange("a2:H" + ws.getLastRow()).clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    ws.getRange("a1").setFormula("=UNIQUE(Sheet1!A:A)");     
  
var unRng = "A2:A" + ws.getLastRow();
  sortRng = "Sheet1!A2:H" + md.getLastRow();

ws.getRange("B2:H2").clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});  

formulaP1 = "=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(" + unRng + ",SORTN(SORT(" + sortRng + ",2,FALSE,1,TRUE)," + ws.getLastRow() + ",2,1,TRUE),"
formulaP2 = ",FALSE))"
mdLC      = md.getLastColumn();

  for (var i = 2; i < mdLC+1; i++) {
      var row = 2
      ws.getRange(row, i).setFormula(formulaP1 + i + formulaP2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with only one formula. Do you actually need a script for this?

This formula in `A1` cell in **Sheet2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  VLOOKUP(
    UNIQUE(Sheet1!A:A),
    {
      Sheet1!A1:H1;
      SORT(Sheet1!A2:H, 5,)
    },
    SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(Sheet1!A:H)),
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: My apologies for the late reply (something to do with a pandemic...) but yes I would like to have this in a script as the formula takes a very long time (sometimes over 2 minutes) to finish as the data is over 10000 lines.

Comment: @Caramel it get the results in a few seconds on 10 000 rows. See [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuxJPNmN9OEz5TNUAg5PQMVawKWfET8jd30FvA-x6d0/edit#gid=274120960&range=A1). Maybe it is actually your script that is causing bad performance. In the example I've disabled all the scripts.

Comment: @Caramel fixed sharing settings.

Comment: Hi Kishkin, for me it takes 1.23 minutes to get the result of the formula for 10.000 lines in Chrome (tested it in your example). My data in Sheet1 is pushed to that Sheet by an script (CSV data) Then the formula should update the data in Sheet2. After updating Sheet2 another scripts is executed. As the formula in Sheet2 takes to much time to finish (and we are only allowed to use Chrome, no other browser) I get a timeout error. Therefore I've requested help to enhance my script. Is it possible to write the outcome of the formula into a array in the script and after that write it to Sheet2?